# Does Pervasive Light stack with Painful Oath?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, avenger

I've got a question about painful oath + pervasive light.

Painful Oath says "The first time you hit..., you deal extra radiant and necrotic damage"

Pervasive Light says "When you hit a target that is vulnerable to radiant damage with AN ATTACK that does not deal radiant damage, you deal extra damage equal to that vulnerability"

If my player hits his oath with a non-radiant power, I apply extra radiant damage (if enemy is radiant vulnerable)
But is is painful oath AN ATTACK?  Should i consider that Painful Oath an attack or just a consequence of the attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you apply the extra radiant damage you're effectively adding the radiant keyword, making it a radiant attack, pervasive light would then not have it's trigger met because the attack deals the proper damage already.

Pervasive light is basically the opportunity to get your vulnerability damage when you're not dealing radiant. Painful Oath lets you deal radiant and deal the vulnerability damage. You can't double dip on that.

To clear up the one mechanical point here, Painful Oath adds damage to the attack and is *not* considered a separate mechanical damage pool (it's "extra" damage, not a separate effect). Again, this reinforces the fact that these powers don't stack.